# Wordpress SQL Issue not returning correct reselts

Tags: users, mysql, wpdb, user-meta, sql

So, I have been working on an SQL query involving the users and usermeta tables in wordpress. I am not getting the correct results. I have the following query written

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    IL9_users 
LEFT JOIN 
    ( 
    SELECT 
        user_id, 
        MAX(case when meta_key = 'first_name' then meta_value end) first_name, 
        MAX(case when meta_key = 'last_name' then meta_value end) last_name
    FROM 
        IL9_usermeta 
    ) AS um 
ON 
    IL9_users.ID = um.user_id
```

This code returns all of the results except the correct values for first_name and last_name. The first value returned is incorrect, but at least it is being returned. All of the other values are null. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: I was able to solve it on my own by using the basic WP query and then running a secondary query that I knew worked on a table I had created via the plugin I built. I cannot post the code as it is too long to fit in this response, but I essentially built 2 foreach loops, first I took the data from the table I needed the original data from and then I did a foreach loop using the data from the basic WP User Query based on the ID of the first foreach loop in order to get the right data needed.

Comment: You should post an answer if you've solved it, instead of adding a comment It's OK to [answer your own question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), and you can even choose to accept it after 48 hours.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer in code form:

```
<?php

// Customer Details

$args = array(
'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
'role'         => 'customer',
'meta_key'     => 'last_name',
'meta_value'   => '',
'meta_compare' => '',
'meta_query'   => array(),
'date_query'   => array(),        
'include'      => array(),
'exclude'      => array(),
'orderby'      => 'last_name',
'order'        => 'ASC',
'offset'       => '',
'search'       => '',
'number'       => '',
'count_total'  => false,
'fields'       => 'all',
'who'          => ''
);


$bowlers = get_users( $args );

global $wpdb;

$games_left = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, user_id, sum(total_games) AS total_games, sum(games_played) AS games_played FROM `bowling_games` GROUP BY user_id");


?>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <h2>Users with 0 Games left</h2>
    <button><a href="" title="">Send Reminder to All</a></button>

    <?php

        foreach ( $games_left as $game_left ) {

            $total_games = $game_left->total_games;
            $games_played = $game_left->games_played;
            $user_id = $game_left->user_id;


            foreach ( $bowlers as $bowler ) {

                if ( $user_id == $bowler->ID ) {


            if ( ( $total_games - $games_played ) == 0 ) { ?>

                <p><?php echo "User ID: " . $user_id . " Name: " . $bowler->first_name . " " . $bowler->last_name . " Email: " . $bowler->user_email  . " Games Left: " . ( $total_games - $games_played ); ?></p>

        <?php       
            }}

        }
        }


    ?>





</div>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

WordPress defines a class called wpdb, which contains a set of functions used to interact with a database.

First to initialize a global object variable, $wpdb, which is an instantiation of the wpdb class defined in /wp-includes/wp-db.php.

```
<?php
    require_once( '../../../wp-config.php' );
    global $wpdb;

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $ID = $current_user->ID;
    $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `user_id` = ".$ID);
    // Where $ID current user id and you can get it by wp_get_current_user() function    
        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            if($data[$k]->meta_key == 'wp_capabilities'){
                $roles = unserialize($data[$k]->meta_value);
                foreach($roles as $key => $val){
                    echo "Key: ".$key."--"."Value: ".$val;
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please take your time and properly format your posts. We cannot continue to clean up your mess.